# Unable to fetch user with specific email and with specific status mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to get a user order with specific email and with status thats in not equal to "Order Completed"  but i am facing error  "Expression $ne takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in." it would be very nice if someone could help me this it. thankyou

code:

```
  let myorders = await orderSchema.find({"userData.email":req.user.email},{status:{$ne:"Order Completed"}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, an error was trying to tell you that find query take 2 arguments

1. query
2. projection

As you have divided your query into 2 objects, which is not correct
you can write your query like this

```
let myorders = await orderSchema.find({
    "userData.email":req.user.email, 
    status:{$ne:"Order Completed"}
})
```

For more details on the "find" query check out the official document [mongo find query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: thanks bro , still i can't figure out why have u  wrote the queries two times like u added the userData.email query 2 times and so did u for status ??

Comment: @nodeDev If this answered worked for you then consider accepting it since this helps upcoming users to know that this is a working solution to this specific problem.

Comment: Sorry @nodeDev, It was a mistake... I have corrected it! Thanks!

Comment: @HandsomeCoder  Thanks alot   for your time and help :)